# How can I use haml within a coffeescript file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, coffeescript

Is it possible to use haml within a coffeescript file in a rails 3.1 project?

What is the correct order of the file extensions?

My last try was that:

### home.js.haml.coffescript

```
$ ->
  alert '#{@count}'
```

where **@count** is a ruby variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct order would be `home.js.coffeescript.haml`—you want the file to first be evaluated as Haml to give you your variables, then compiled as CoffeeScript, then finally served as JavaScript.

However, I strongly suspect that the Haml processor will choke on some CoffeeScript syntax. It would probably be safer to use ERB, which should work for your example.